# Explanation of Python result on list append

Tags: python, list, append

When I tried something in Python, I encountered something strange:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]

b = [x.append(5) for x in a]
```

It turns out `b` is `[None, None]` rather than `[[1,2,5], [3,4,5]]`. I think it's related to the fact list is mutable, but not quite sure what exactly happens in this case. Could any of you explain? Thank you.

Comment: `list.append` returns `None`. You can check this for yourself: `print([].append(3))`

Comment: Note, by *convention* mutator methods on mutable types in the standard library do not return `None`, but that is not a language guarantee, and it isn't even a strict convention, note `my_list.pop()` is a mutator method and it doesn't return `None`

Answer (score 1):

`append` always returns `None`; you call it solely for its side effect on the object (in this case, `x`).